# how the threads in an executor framework are kept alive till we call shutdown?

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

how the threads in an executor framework are kept alive till we call shutdown? how these threads are designed internally to be alive ?normal threads will die once their task is done. I want to understand this. Please help.

Comment: `Normal threads will die once their task is done` > It is actually a hint, simply  make the thread busy either blocking it til a new task is queued.

Answer (score 0):

It works like below：

```
public class Demo {

    private static final class Worker implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Runnable task = getTaskFromQueue();
            while (task != null) {
                task.run();
                task = getTaskFromQueue();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Worker worker = new Worker();
        Thread thread = new Thread(worker);
        thread.start();
    }

}
```